# i want to get some row values as column day wise for one month

Tags: mysql

i want to get some row values as column sum of which column is reading date basis

```
SELECT * FROM `mitre_details`;

id       reading            date
1         500               2019-07-15
2         300               2019-07-15
3         600               2019-07-15
4         800               2019-07-15
5         900               2019-07-15
1         200               2019-07-16
2         250               2019-07-16
3         400               2019-07-16
4         550               2019-07-16
5         790               2019-07-16
```

Tried Query:

```
SELECT date,sum(reading) FROM `mitre_details` GROUP BY date;
```

Desired Output:

```
Date          Reading    Mitre 1    Mitre 2   Mitre 3   Mitre 4   Mitre 5
2019-07-15     3100       500         300       600       800       900
2019-07-16     2190       200         250       400       550       790
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code. Also, your query cannot produce the sample result shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: i need date wise all mitre reading show and sum of all mitre reading per day

Comment: Yes. See comments above. 2 options provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
select `date`,
sum(reading) Reading,
group_concat(case when id=1 then reading end) m1,
group_concat(case when id=2 then reading end) m2,
group_concat(case when id=3 then reading end) m3,
group_concat(case when id=4 then reading end) m4,
group_concat(case when id=5 then reading end) m5
from mitre_details group by `date`;
```

Comment: mitre 1  value is comming rest of mitre value is null

Comment: can you share create tbl schema

Comment: CREATE TABLE `mitre_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reading` double NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
)

Comment: with data too? so that i could check from my local

Comment: INSERT INTO `mitre_details` (`id`, `reading`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 500, '2019-07-15'),
(2, 300, '2019-07-15'),
(3, 600, '2019-07-15'),
(4, 800, '2019-07-15'),
(5, 900, '2019-07-15'),
(1, 200, '2019-07-16'),
(2, 250, '2019-07-16'),
(3, 400, '2019-07-16'),
(4, 550, '2019-07-16'),
(5, 790, '2019-07-16');

Comment: please tell me solution above problem